# Confusion about Affine Toric Varieties/ Toric Ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I have just started reading about Toric varieties from David Cox and I have a couple of very basic questions about toric ideals and aff. toric varieties.

1) Eventually, a toric ideal can be defined as a prime ideal generated by differences of two monomials. I am a little confused with the definition of a monomial in this context. In all of the examples and all the proofs in the book, from what I can tell it is implied that the coefficient of the monomial should always be 1, meaning that $X$ is monomial but $2X$ isn't.

That seems a bit weird to me, as that would mean that $V(X-Y)$ is an affine toric variety and $V(X-2Y)$ isn't, unless we can somehow write $I=\langle X-2Y \rangle$ as an ideal generated by difference of monomials with coefficient one, which I don't see how. So is $V(X-2Y)$ not an affine toric variety?

2) Given that the ideal of an affine toric variety is a toric ideal, meaning that it is generated by binomials, I am confused as to what happens when you for example parallel translate an affine toric variety. For example, let $V=V(X-Y)$ an affine toric variety and translate it to $W=V+w$ where $w$ is any vector in $\mathbb R^2$, say $w=(0,2)$. Clearly $W$ is isomorphic to $V$ where the morphism is also a group homomorphism. Doesn't that however imply that $W$ is also an affine toric variety? But if that is the case, I fail to see how $I(W)=\langle X-Y+2\rangle$ is generated by binomials (i.e is a toric ideal).

Comment: I guess you still don't see the definition but you are looking now at the toric subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^n$, that is, the subvarieties for which the inclusion map is a toric morphism. That's why your definition is not stable under translations. The ideal of the translation will be generated by binomials but the variables on the binomials will be the translation of the original variables.

Comment: Now for the first question, the idea of toric varieties is that the coordinate ring is a "semigroup-algebra", that is, is like a polynomial ring but there is an equivalent relation over the exponents of the monomials. Then you only have equalities of the form $X^\alpha Y^\beta=X^\gamma Y^\delta$. Something like $X=2Y$ doesn't work for this.

Comment: @nowheredense this seems like it would work well as an answer! Would you care to record your remarks below?